# students Database Management System

Tags: c, fopen, scanf

I am creating a small DBMS that records students name, mat#, department and major.

I am using a text file as my database; my program should add new students, search students, delete students, update students info etc. For now, I'm adding students info to the database and its working fine, but what I want is to continuously add students without running the program again until I press a key.

So, I used a loop (both do while loop and while loop) and it's working fine, but I can't append them to the database. I don't know what is going wrong.

If I don't use a loop, it will append it to the database, but if I use a loop, it will not append it.

```
/*
 * Files.c
 *
 *  Created on: Mar 2, 2015
 *      Author: ousainou
 */

    # include <stdio.h>
    # include <stdlib.h>

    void appending();
    void readFile();


    main()
    {

        //printf("do you want to add a student[y/n]");
         printf("*********************************\n");
         printf("*Students Management System(SMS)*\n");
         printf("*********************************\n");
        printf("press '1' to add a new student\n");
        printf("press '2' to view all students records\n");
        //frintf("press '3' to view a a student's information");
        //printf("press '4' to edit a student's infomation);
        //printf("press '5' to delete a student);
        int input;
        scanf("%d",&input);
        int x= 0;
        do{
        //do{
        if(input == 1)
        {
        appending();
        }
        else if(input == 2)
        {
            readFile();
        }
        printf("press -1 to exit");
        scanf("%d",&input);
        if(input == -1)
            break;

        }while(x == 0);
}
            int input;

            char firstname[20];

            char lastname[20];

            char mat_number[10];

            char department[10];

            char major[20];
            char read;
            int num = 1;
            int count = 0;

    void appending()
    {
        FILE*file = fopen("new file.txt","a");

        printf("enter first name\n");
        scanf("%s", firstname);

        printf("enter second name\n");
        scanf("%s", lastname );

        printf("enter mat number\n");
        scanf("%s", mat_number);

        printf("enter department\n");
        scanf("%s", department);

        printf("enter major\n");
        scanf("%s", major);

        fprintf(file,"\t\t%s\t\t%s\t\t%s\t\t%s\t\t%s\n",firstname,lastname,mat_number,department,major);
        if(file)
                {
                    printf("%s %s%s",firstname,lastname,"'s information has been stored\n");
                }
                else
                {
                    printf("database not found ");
                }

    }

    void readFile()
    {

            FILE*rfile = fopen("new file.txt","r");


        if(!rfile)
                {
                    printf("file not found");
                    exit(-1);
                }
                else
                {
                    do{
                        read = fgetc(rfile);

                        printf("%c",read);

                        }while(read != EOF);

                }


    }
```

Answer (score 0):

you need to close the file, once it open you can write continuously but it does not read new values on your read function(because it open as a new). after reading also you may not need to keep the file open. use `fclose()`

```
/*
 * Files.c
 *
 *  Created on: Mar 2, 2015
 *      Author: ousainou
 */

    # include <stdio.h>
    # include <stdlib.h>

    void appending();
    void readFile();


int main()
    {

        //printf("do you want to add a student[y/n]");
         printf("*********************************\n");
         printf("*Students Management System(SMS)*\n");
         printf("*********************************\n");

        do{ 
            printf("press '1' to add a new student\n");
            printf("press '2' to view all students records\n");
            printf("press -1 to exit");
        //frintf("press '3' to view a a student's information");
        //printf("press '4' to edit a student's infomation);
        //printf("press '5' to delete a student);
        int input;
        scanf("%d",&input);
        //do{
        if(input == 1)
        {
        appending();
        }
        else if(input == 2)
        {
            readFile();
        }
        else if(input == -1)
        {
            break;
        }

        }while(true);
}

            int input;

            char firstname[20];

            char lastname[20];

            char mat_number[10];

            char department[10];

            char major[20];
            char read;
            int num = 1;
            int count = 0;

    void appending()
    {
        FILE* file = fopen("new file.txt","a");

        printf("enter first name\n");
        scanf("%s", firstname);

        printf("enter second name\n");
        scanf("%s", lastname );

        printf("enter mat number\n");
        scanf("%s", mat_number);

        printf("enter department\n");
        scanf("%s", department);

        printf("enter major\n");
        scanf("%s", major);

        fprintf(file,"\t\t%s\t\t%s\t\t%s\t\t%s\t\t%s\n",firstname,lastname,mat_number,department,major);
        if(file)
                {
                    printf("%s %s%s",firstname,lastname,"'s information has been stored\n");
                    fclose(file);
                }
                else
                {
                    printf("database not found ");
                }

    }

    void readFile()
    {

            FILE* rfile = fopen("new file.txt","r");


        if(!rfile)
                {
                    printf("file not found");
                    exit(-1);
                }
                else
                {
                    do{
                        read = fgetc(rfile);

                        printf("%c",read);

                        }while(read != EOF);
                    fclose(rfile);
                }


    }
```

Comment: Thanks bro. I've tried that and its working. Do you know how can i search for a specific student by just typing his/her mat number

Comment: here what i do. use a data structure like Linked list or tree. once run, the program should read the file and put them in a data structure. and also when i insert a new entry it also put in to the data structure. and when i need to search some one, then i can simply use a search method according to my structure. 
or read the file line by line, split the line and take the mat number and check it.   
you may need to consider about the size of the data base also.

Comment: well i suggest that, start it first (as you wish to do. ). and post it as a new question. so the peoples will help from there. (if you post the link here I can notice it too). and dont forget to accept the answer if you satisfied :) .

Comment: Okay I'll do that and can I also use an array to do it

Comment: @ous may be you can. first, think how you gonna do it. then try to convert it to code. if can't, post here.